# Smooth scroll down between divs

Tags: jquery, scroll

Don't know if some one can help me, i'm trying to build a porfolio with a smooth effect en scrolling down, this is the effect that i wont to do: https://studiorotate.com/case-study/seedlip

Comment: Have you consider using a library such as [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). It will save you lots of headaches regarding browser compatibility, touch swiping, responsiveness, callbacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial by w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll)

What you need to do: 
Add id's to the sections of your page:

```
<a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <section style="background-color:blue"></section>
</div>
```

And then add the jquery file along with the script from w3schools like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

And then upon clicking the `<a href="#section2"></a>` tag, you'll be smooth scrolled to #section2

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41fa8n5v/) for the same.